# (JQuery) Moving an element with key presses?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("html").keydown(function(event){

        if(event.which == "37")
            $("#hero").animate({"left" : "-=30px"});

        if(event.which == "39")
            $("#hero").animate({"left" : "+=30px"});

        if(event.which == "38")
            $("#hero").animate({"top" : "-=30px"});

        if(event.which == "40")
            $("#hero").animate({"top" : "+=30px"});
});
```

There seems to be a queue of all the keys that has been pressed,
and I need this queue to be empty when the direction is changed.
Because if I keep the left key pressed for a few seconds and then press right, 
the "#hero" will go left for a long time and then go right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to stop the current animation to avoid that. Try this.

```
$("html").keydown(function(event){

        if(event.which == "37")
            $("#hero").stop(true).animate({"left" : "-=30px"});

        if(event.which == "39")
            $("#hero").stop(true).animate({"left" : "+=30px"});

        if(event.which == "38")
            $("#hero").stop(true).animate({"top" : "-=30px"});

        if(event.which == "40")
            $("#hero").stop(true).animate({"top" : "+=30px"});
});
```

`.stop( [clearQueue] [, jumpToEnd] )` reference: http://api.jquery.com/stop/

> clearQueue - Boolean indicating whether to remove queued animation
>   as well. Defaults to false. 
>   jumpToEndA - Boolean indicating whether to
>   complete the current animation immediately. Defaults to false.

Comment: For moving element diagonally change the `left` and `top` values together.

Comment: How? For each time the event function is called, the keyCode property contains only one value, how can I check if both keys are pressed (top and left)?

Comment: You will have to use keyup event also and keep track of keys whether it is released or not and act accordingly. I think this answer has answered your question you should open a new question for that.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#hero").stop().animate( ... );
```

Should be enough

Answer (score 0):

If you don't queue the animations then you can let the element animate diagonally:

```
$("html").keydown(function(event){
    if(event.which == "37") $("#hero").animate({"left" : "-=30px"}, { queue : false });

    if(event.which == "39") $("#hero").animate({"left" : "+=30px"}, { queue : false });

    if(event.which == "38") $("#hero").animate({"top" : "-=30px"}, { queue : false });

    if(event.which == "40") $("#hero").animate({"top" : "+=30px"}, { queue : false });
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/x5Tn4/

Answer (score 0):

Check my [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/gFcuU/97/) in which I use max of 2 key strokes for smooth transition.